# how to return a deferred object on a phonegap class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-deferred

ill start with an example:

```
jQuery.when(setLocation()).then(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});

function setLocation(){
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setLcationSuccess, onGeoError);
}

function setLcationSuccess(position) {
    return position.coords.latitude; // 33.5554444
}
```

in this example `e` is undefined. I need to get whatever `setLcationSuccess()` returns

i need to run `setLocation()` with a deferred obj so i know when the coords are ready

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery.when(setLocation()).then(function(e) {
    console.log('a', e);
});

function setLocation(){
    var d = $.Deferred();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        d.resolveWith(this, [position.coords.latitude]);
    }, function(){
        d.reject();
    });
    return d.promise();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HekMX/)

Comment: I have suggestions for improvement on the accepted answer.  For example: not using `$.when()`/`.then()` and you should probably consistently use either `.resolveWith()`/`.rejectWith()` or `.resolve()`/`.reject()`.  code/comments on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HekMX/4/